# The value which I wish to print is too long and it cannot print all the value from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

[image]

I would like to print out the hash value from my firebase, but it cannot print it out all due to the screen size. How can I solve it?

```
func loadHashData() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("hashedpdf").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let hashedpdf = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
        self.hashLabel.text = "The hashed values of chosen pdf is: \(hashedpdf)"
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.hashLabel.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.hashLabel.numberOfLines = 0` or use `UITextView` which can be scrollable

Comment: It still remain the same output. What is the meaning of numberOfLines?

Comment: `To remove any maximum limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.` It controls the lines that are allowed to show. If it doesn't work probably you have restricted the label's height

Comment: Alright,thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0):

Make your `UILabel` to have constraints to top, left and right only (a.k.a. **no** height constraint), then:

```
<#UILabel#>.numberOfLines = 0
<#UILabel#>.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Not sure about your full code details, but you may also have to:

```
<#UILabel#>.sizeToFit()
<#UILabel#>.layoutIfNeeded()
```

---

Note that this is more related to the label creation, not on the Firebase request (code you provided).

Comment: Thanks ! It works at the first line, which means now I can print the output : "The hashed value of chosen" but I still cannot print the continue value at the second line

Comment: check the constraints, you should have top, left and right.

Comment: let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 300, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)) - is it like this?

Comment: no, using AutoLayout, you can set the frame to `.zero` and use NSLayoutConstraints.